# React: useState() vs useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I’ve gone through the React Docs once.

I’m trying to compare useState() with useRef() in my mind…

Commonalities to both useState() and useRef():

- Available in functional components only
- Create static values – value persists between function calls
- Values are mutable
- Are scoped within their function component
- Scope includes other hooks (use’s) within their function component

Differences between useState() and useRef():

- useState triggers re-render, useRef does not.
- useRef can reference child elements (via “ref={}”), useState can’t.
- For child DOM elements, ref={} refers to the DOM element itself.
- For child React components, ref={} refers to the child component itself.

…And [this previous Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455887/react-usestate-or-useref) adds:

- useState updates it’s value asynchronously, useRef updates synchronously.

So I have 3 questions so far:

1. Are the above commonalities & differences correct?
2. Any other commonalities or differences I should be aware of?
3. From the component that creates the reference (useRef+ref={}), can I both get & set values on the child component (yes, it may/may not be wise to do so)?

Comment: Both are used for different purposes, there is no comparison per se

Answer (score 7):

Basically your comparison is correct, but as already was mentioned in comments they serve different purposes. You just need to know is that `useRef` basically is [syntax sugar](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1099842565631819776):

> useRef() is basically useState({current: initialValue })[0]