# JS/React: queue to store and sync API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, queue

The goal is to create a queue to store API requests.

Expected result:

- every time the `Add` button is pressed, the request should be added to the queue;
- once `Sync` button is pressed, all API requests from the queue should be fired and cleared

Here's what I've tried so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sky-e23w6?file=/src/App.js

There are a few problems here:

- API calls are not fired;
- `_store` gets cleared every time a new request is added;
- sync is not working.
- how can I store API request config?

How can this be solved? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The queue must be stored as state of a React component. What you need is the `useState` or `useRef` hook. The latter is better in your case because you already have implemented a `BoxEventProcessor` and you do not need to re-render any component when an `add`/`submit` button is clicked. (see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56456055/6238076))

```
const App = () => {
  const sendEventToServer = async (id) => { ... };

  const refBoxEventProcessor = React.useRef(
    createSerialProcessor(sendEventToServer)
  );

  const submit = (id) => {
    refBoxEventProcessor.current.addEvent(`param-${id}`, new Date().toString());
  };

  const onSync = () => {
    refBoxEventProcessor.current.processEvents();
  };

  return (<>...</>);
```

Above is a minimum example for `useRef()`. Its argument is an newly created instance of `SerialProcessor`, which will be stored in the object `refBoxEventProcessor` under the `current` property.
It will be persistent upon latter re-rendering.
All the user's "API requests" are stored in the queue of this object until the user click the `sync` button to clear the queue.

You might elaborate on the initialization (`useRef`) and `submit` functions to better fit your needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-so-70387163-0yqi5