# useRef underline current is changed but it will not paint to dom

Tags: reactjs

Why it is not re-rendering the component even though current is changed. I know it can be done with useState.

```
 const onDecrement = () => {
    counter.current -= 1;
  };

  const onIncrement = () => {
    counter.current += 1;
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    counter.current = 0;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   // It should trigger this
    console.log('re-render'); 
  }, [counter.current]);
```

Playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xtamop?file=useFetch.tsx,App.tsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455887/react-usestate-or-useref

Comment: Literally *"Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render"* [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref:~:text=Keep%20in%20mind%20that%20useRef%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20notify%20you%20when%20its%20content%20changes.%20Mutating%20the%20.current%20property%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20cause%20a%20re%2Drender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useRef are used to avoid re-render as opposed to useState which causes re-render when change happens.

As for your context, you can assign the ref to the div element and use the `inntertext` to assign values

```
  const counter = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const onDecrement = () => {
    counter.current.innerText = `${Number(counter.current.innerText) - 1}`;
  };

  const onIncrement = () => {
    counter.current.innerText = `${Number(counter.current.innerText) + 1}`;
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    counter.current.innerText = '0';
  };


 // only executes in the initial render
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('re-render');
    counter.current.innerText = '0';
  }, [counter.current]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
      <div
        ref={counter}
        style={{ display: 'inline-block', margin: '0 10px' }}
      ></div>
      <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
      <div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
        <button onClick={onReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-npzvpm?file=useFetch.tsx,App.tsx)